# Странное поведение строковых переменных (меняются с того ни с сего)

Tags: c++, кодировка, строки, c++builder

```
UnicodeString gorod; // глобальная
void __fastcall TForm1::DBLookupComboBox2Click(TObject *Sender)
{   wchar_t *other =L"Другой";
    UnicodeString pr=ADOQuery2->FieldByName("Название")->AsString;
    if(wcscmp(other,pr.w_str())!=0)
    {
        gorod=ADOQuery2->FieldByName("Идентификатор")->AsString;
    }
    else
    {
        Form3->Visible = true;
    }
    wchar_t *s1 = L"http://xoap.weather.com/weather/local/";
    wchar_t *s2 = L"?cc=*&dayf=5&link=xoap&prod=xoap&unit=m&par=1171574135&key=a3740f391c3a72ee";
    wchar_t *s3; s3 = gorod.w_str();
    wcscat(s1,s3);
    wcscat(s1,s2);
    wchar_t *s4 = GetCurrentDir().w_str();
    wchar_t *s5 = L"\\pogoda.xml";
    wcscat(s4,s5);
    URLDownloadToFile(0, s1, s4, 0, 0);
}
```

**Первый проход:**

> other="Другой";   pr="Мурманск";
>
> gorod="RSXX0452";
>
> s3="RSXX0452";
>
> s2 =
> L"?cc=*&dayf=5&link=xoap&prod=xoap&unit=m&par=1171574135&key
> =a3740f391c3a72ee"; // после выполнения 17-ой строчки значение
> s2="SXX0452", после 18-ой
> s2="SXX0452SXX0452". С какого
> перепуга??
>
> s1=L"http://xoap.weather.com/weather/local/";
> // из-за глюка в s2 прибавилось
> "SXX0452SXX0452" на выполнении 18-ой
> строки.
>
> s4=L"C:\Users\Алиса\Documents\RAD
> Studio\Projects\Pro2\Win32\Debug";
> // после 21-ой строчки
> L"C:\Users\Алиса\Documents\RAD
> Studio\Projects\Pro2\Win32\Debug\pogoda.xml"
> - как и должно быть.
>
> s5=L"\pogoda.xml";

**Второй проход:** выбираем любой другой город, в начале функции s1,s2,s3 имеют просто кракозябры, потом присваиваются значения, которые заданы в функции, но почему-то присваиваются предыдущие значения (и обнулять пыталась, и команду delete применять - все бесполезно). С s4 и s5, вроде, все нормально. Когда я пыталась менять строчки местами, тоже такие симптомы имелись, от безысходности делала переменные глобальными, меняла эти кодировки, тогда возникали ошибки хлеще. Естественно, на втором прогоне программа вылетает, так как возникает перегрузка памяти. 
Из-за чего такая аномалия? Два дня уже этим страдаю.

Для справки: Builder XE5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в `wcscat`. Эта функция ведёт себя не так, как вы предполагаете. Она не довыделяет память, а пишет «в хвост», предполагая, что **вы** дали ей достаточно памяти. Поскольку вы этого не сделали, затирается чужая память, то есть, что угодно, «на кого бог пошлёт».

Вторая проблема — строка

```
wchar_t *s1 = L"http://xoap.weather.com/weather/local/";
```

Строковые константы имеют const-тип, использование их как не-констант может приводить к любому виду проблем. (А вы таки используете их как не-константы.)

У вас есть два пути. Либо вы пишете на настоящем C++, и *никогда* не пользуетесь `wchar_t*` (а только `wstring`) — там операции ведут себя намного проще, и управление памятью берут на себя. Либо вы садитесь за K&R и учите наизусть, чтоб аж от зубов отскакивало, как ведут себя строки в чистом C. Третьего пути нет.

---

P. S.: Не воспринимайте это как личный выпад. C++-строки *действительно* ведут себя намного проще и естественнее, чем C-строки. Поэтому в краткосрочной перспективе вам стоит просто перейти на C++-строки (`wstring`), и забыть о непреднамеренном разрушении памяти как о страшном сне. В долгосрочной перспективе вам всё же стоит изучить поведение C-строк. Оно тоже логично и обладает внутренней красотой, хотя и достаточно непривычно (и тем самым чревато разнообразными ошибками) для тех, кто сталкивается с ним впервые.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Очень хорошо разжевали.

Comment: @4lice: Пожалуйста!